# Why is not my variable in Gradle script not defined?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-flavors

What I want to do is to create 6 different variants, each with little varying AndroidManifest. The data is calculated dynamically, so I can't simply put it into `variant/AndroidManifest.xml` by hand.

When I run the build script for a specific variant, say 'TinyDebug', it doesn't do what I would like it to do. In this case, I would like it to have version code 1501.

I've edited the script heavily here, to make it more readable. Due to the complexity of data calculations, I'd rather have them in a task (on which initialize task depends on).

Question: Why is version_code calculated incorrectly in AndroidManifest? How should I perform my calculations so that they could factor in the flavor, and pass their outputs to `AndroidManifest.xml`?

build.gradle

```
def int version_code_suffix = -1    //-1 means it is erronous or unset

task initialize{    
    doFirst{
        android.productFlavors.tiny {
            version_code_suffix = 1
        }
    }
}

android {
    productFlavors {
        tiny {
            versionCode 1500 + version_code_suffix
        }
    }
    tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        if (task.name == 'processTinyDebugResources') {
            task.dependsOn initialize
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml after build (it should be 1501)

```
android:versionCode = 1499
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define it as a project variable if you will be using it everywhere as shown below.

```
project.ext.version_code_suffix = -1    //-1 means it is erronous or unset

task initialize{    
    doFirst{
        android.productFlavors.tiny {
            version_code_suffix = 1
        }
    }
}

android {
    productFlavors {
        tiny {
            versionCode 1500 + version_code_suffix
        }
    }
    tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        if (task.name == 'processTinyDebugResources') {
            task.dependsOn initialize
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It just runs through all the android.projectFlavors.*, and keeps the latest values. Changing their order changes the results.